# Spring MVC uri mapping with percent encoded characters

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, encoding

I have a spring mvc application that runs on Tomcat 7 with http and ajp connectors configured with URIEncoding="UTF-8".
My REST controller fragments:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("")
public class ClientRestApi {
    private final String API_PREFIX = "/api/1.0/client";
    ...
    @RequestMapping(value = API_PREFIX + "/{clientId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public ClientDetails get(@PathVariable String clientId, HttpServletRequest request) {
        log.info("Client API GET [" + clientId + "] | " + request.getRequestURI());
        ...
    }
}
```

- When i go to: `http://www.example.pl/api/1.0/client/abc` i get *abc* client page - **correct**
- When i go to: `http://www.example.pl/%07api/1.0/client/abc` i get *abc* client page - **wrong**
- When i go to: `http://www.example.pl/%0bapi/1.0/client/abc` i get *abc* client page - **wrong**
- When i go to: `http://www.example.pl/ap%0bi/1.0/client/abc` i get http 404 - **correct**

In application log i can see (for first 3 requests):

```
ClientRestApi - Client API GET [abc] | /api/1.0/client/abc
ClientRestApi - Client API GET [abc] | /%07api/1.0/client/abc
ClientRestApi - Client API GET [abc] | /%0bapi/1.0/client/abc
```

My question is why does my **wrong** examples are wrong? **Why they are not http 404?**

In web.xml file in application i have CharacterEncodingFilter filter with UTF-8 encoding. I have never had any issues with wrong encoding in my application.

Edit:
From extended logs, request http://www.example.pl/%0bapi/1.0/client/abc gives:

```
DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /^Kapi/1.0/client/abc
TRACE RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Found 1 matching mapping(s) for [/^Kapi/1.0/client/abc] : [{[/api/1.0/client/{
clientId}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}]
DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Returning handler method [public ClientDetails ...ClientRestApi.get(java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AntPathMatcher tokenizes the path and by default trims all segments (see the Javadoc for String.trim). This behavior can be controlled. For you can configure the RequestMappingHandlerMapping with an AntPathMatcher with setTrimTokens(false).

Comment: In case anyone wonder how this can be done, I've managed to achieve it by using a configuration class extending `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` and then a method like this:

`@Bean
 public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
  RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping = super.requestMappingHandlerMapping();
  AntPathMatcher antPathMatcher = new AntPathMatcher();
  antPathMatcher.setTrimTokens(false);
  handlerMapping.setPathMatcher(antPathMatcher);
  return handlerMapping;
 }`

Answer (score 0):

This is my guest but it seems to be that URL Pattern parser is searching for the presence of `"/api/1.0/client"`. All of your examples have that string present so performing a search string for `API_PREFIX` would return true for them.

http://www.example.pl/%07`api/1.0/client`/abc

http://www.example.pl/%0b`api/1.0/client`/abc

Your last example does not have the exact
`/api/1.0/client` string but instead uses `0bi/1.0/client`.

**Short Answer:** You don't have to define an exact URL for the parser to make a selection. I believe the same is true for regular Java EE without spring. If you define `/api/1.0/client/*` in your web.xml file, any URL that has that string wil trigger the dedicated controller you've assigned to it. Even if the string is preceeded but garbage such as `/SDSFDFSFSFSF/api/1.0/client`

Comment: I checked your solution but it is not true. When i go to: `www.example.pl/xapi/1.0/client/abc` or `www.example.pl/x/api/1.0/client/abc` i always get http 404 - correct behavior. I noticed that this strange behavior occurs only when percent encoded characters are put at the beginning of uri path.